# SQL Order and group by

Tags: sql

I'm getting a bit lost in making a query that performs a certain look up.
I have the first part of the query going, which returns me all accounts that have missing some entries on their account. Now I need to filter this subset further based on their last login attempt.

The table structures are as follows:

- The users table contains all user information. We only care about users under project_id 33.
- The users_account_list contains all accounts a user has. We only care about users NOT having an entry for service 50.
- The users_login_logs contains all login attempts for a user.

The original query I have this this:

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.login, 
       u.email, 
       u.nickname,
       b.station_login AS "additionals.station_login",
       a.id AS "user_account_list.id",
       a.game_id AS "user_account_list.game_id",
       a.game_uid AS "user_account_list.game_uid",
       c.created_at AS "last login"
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_account_list a ON u.id = a.user_id AND a.game_id = 50
LEFT JOIN user_additionals b ON u.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN user_login_logs c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE u.project_id = 33
AND u.verified_at IS NOT NULL
AND (a.id IS NULL OR a.game_id IS NULL OR a.game_uid IS NULL)
AND (b.station_login IS NULL OR b.station_login = '')
ORDER BY c.created_at DESC
```

This returns me all users that have been registered under project_id 33, and do not have an entry for game_id 50, and have no information stored in their additional info table. Optional, but not relevant, Just limits the data returned. It does give me multiple rows per user back , sorted according their latest login date.

What I need is to get only 1 row per user returned with their LATEST login date. *I tried replacing the ORDER BY with GROUP by u.id* but this gives me the oldest result back, not the latest.

How can I:

- Limit the rows returned to only 1 row per user
- Make sure the row is based on the latest login attempt of the user.

*EDIT*:

This is what the query currently returns:

```
+----+-------+-----------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
| id | login | email           | nickname | additionals.station_login | user_account_list.id | user_account_list.game_id | user_account_list.game_uid | last login          |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | usrnm | someon@mail.com | Nickname |                           |                 NULL |                      NULL | NULL                       | 2012-10-19 00:00:00 |
|  1 | usrnm | someon@mail.com | Nickname |                           |                 NULL |                      NULL | NULL                       | 2012-10-18 00:00:00 |
|  1 | usrnm | someon@mail.com | Nickname |                           |                 NULL |                      NULL | NULL                       | 2012-10-17 00:00:00 |
+----+-------+-----------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace your `ORDER BY` by a `GROUP by u.id` as you tried but you also need in your SELECT to indicate that you want the last date in the group so you need to replace

```
c.created_at AS "last login"
```

by

```
MAX(c.created_at) AS "last login"
```

This will return only one line per user thanks to the `GROUP BY` and you will only select the latest date for each user thanks to `MAX()`

Edit: I think you should avoid using alias column names with spaces inside to avoid mistakes

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this, is to `JOIN` the table `user_login_logs`, with the following table:

```
   SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) LatestDate
   FROM user_login_logs 
   GROUP BY user_id
```

and join it on `created_at = LatestDate`. This will limit the users login logs to the latest created date for each user. Here  is your query:

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.login, 
       u.email, 
       u.nickname,
       b.station_login AS "additionals.station_login",
       a.id AS "user_account_list.id",
       a.game_id AS "user_account_list.game_id",
       a.game_uid AS "user_account_list.game_uid",
       c.created_at AS "last login"
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_account_list a ON u.id = a.user_id AND a.game_id = 50
LEFT JOIN user_additionals b ON u.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN user_login_logs c ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) LatestDate
   FROM user_login_logs 
   GROUP BY user_id
) maxc ON c.userid = maxc.userid AND c.created_at = maxc.LatestDate
WHERE u.project_id = 33
AND u.verified_at IS NOT NULL
AND (a.id IS NULL OR a.game_id IS NULL OR a.game_uid IS NULL)
AND (b.station_login IS NULL OR b.station_login = '')
ORDER BY c.created_at DESC;
```

**Note that:** You are `LEFT JOIN` the table, so that the unmatched rows from the left joined table will be included in the result set. If you didn't need to include them in the result set, use `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: This got me closer, but the response below seemed to returned what I want. Thanks for the nice explanation though.